# KB5003637 - no printer available

Tags: windows, printer, updates

A customer can't print since this morning.

Services.msc > Spooler is not activated, although it should start as the PC boots.

You can start the service but you can't choose a printer in Word/Adobe etc. - After trying to print, the spooler service shuts down.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling KB5003637 and restarting the PC should solve this issue. After that, the Spooler Service starts automatically. Also the Spooler Service doesn't deactivate itself as you try to print, so it is possible to print as usual.

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing Windows Updates. There were Printing issues a month or so ago but these were resolved by corrective updates.

Uninstalling an update may be a short term workaround but Systems should be kept up to date for the long term.

[Printing Issues](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-health/resolved-issues-windows-10-2004)

> Unexpected results when printing from some apps or to some printers
>
> OS Build 19041.867  Resolved  2021-03-18
>
> Error when attempting to print to certain printers
>
> OS Build 19041.867  Resolved  2021-03-15

If Windows is up to date, then look for a newer Printer Driver and install that. Windows often updates Printer drivers.

Comment: In addition to what @John says.. (good answer).. you can probably disable spooling to the printer as a temporary workaround.  It will take longer to print and eat the s*it out of your CPU.. but will probably work.

Comment: @John The client was up-to-date, no updates in the queue.

Comment: I adjusted my answer to include updating the driver (Windows often updates printer drivers).  If not a driver issue, then it gets messy after that.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the KB5003637 security update. Windows being up to date is nice and all, but the QA on this particular release was lacking and should be avoided for the near future.

You can uninstall by going to updates, history, uninstall. Reboot and let it do it's thing. Should fix any graphical issues if they are present too.